# Do we need multiple work flow for branches if one of the job not required to perform from main in Github

Tags: github-actions

For my Feature branch I want to skip the deployment job, but for main branch I need a deployment. I have created a single workflow for it. Trigger I mentioned both main and feature/* . But how to skip the deploy job if it is a feature branch? Do I need to create a new workflow for the deploy and add only main to trigger or is there any way in a single workflow I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a condition on the deploy job to trigger only in your `main` branch

```
if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}
```

as stated in the documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#about-context-and-expressions